# C# - Event is not detected on Windows XP - USB drive

Tags: c#, windows-7, insert, windows-xp, usb

I´m new to C# -- started three days ago because of an especific need regarding usb drives. Reading here and there I could have the following code to work. What I want is to know when an user inserts a pendrive in the usb port.

The only problem is the that on XP32 (the only XP I tested) the event will never be detected. On Windows 7 it runs perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace X
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
            watcher.Query = query;
            watcher.Start();
            watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
         // DO something if a pen drive (or any storage device) is inserted.
         // Works fine on Windows 7
         // XP will ignore the event... 
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be very welcome!

Regards,

Sergio

Comment: This might work for you: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/13/how-can-i-determine-when-a-removable-drive-gets-connected.aspx

Comment: Take a look at this link it may be a better alternative to what you are doing .. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3946/Trapping-windows-messages

Comment: WqlEventQuery does not support Windows XP. So this method cannot be used. Looking into the class in more detail previous versions DID support Windows XP. What version of the .NET Framework are you using? Which means the reason this is not working is actually because `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` does not support Windows XP.  Which is also not true based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394516(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.query%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you need XP service pack 3 for it to work (SP2 on x64).

Comment: Ramhound, gaynorvader  and DJ KRAZE, thanks for your replies. My configuration is: XP 32 w/ SP3, .net fw 3.5. Regarding this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394516(v=vs.85).aspx) it says the Minimum supported client is Windows XP [desktop apps only] what seems to be wrong. I converted my application to windows form (also to run as service) and it didn´t work. Will take a close look to your suggestions and post the results soon. I´m sure this matter will be helpfull to more people. Regards!